# How to make my app available in other countries with only english support

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

Hi I am releasing my app to app store for first time and I am wondering how I can release my app to be available in other countries than English speaking countries when I only have English version of the app.

For example, I had many experiences when I lived in Hong Kong and (with Hong Kong iTunes Account) that I couldn't download many apps because it said it was not supported in Hong Kong app store and it would take me to US app store. But since my iTunes account was made in Hong Kong I couldn't download them in the US store anyway. This also happened to me in Korea with my Korea account.

I always have my iPhone language setting to English so I am not sure what is keeping me from downloading the games or the apps with English version. The pattern that I assume is that I only can download the English version of the app IF the app also supports Chinese or Korean just because my iTunes account was made in Hong Kong or Korea.

Now that it's my turn to release the app, I want to have a clear understanding on this and know whether my app will be available in other countries like Hong Kong or Korea with English support only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set up your app in iTunes Connect, by default, it is available worldwide. You are also given the option to override that, if you'd like.

If You want to make your App available for certain countries, then also you can do it by going to Pricing section in the iTunes connect and can choose particular countries.

Like this
[image]

**NB :** *But if you want to make the app available worldwide, you don't need to choose country, By default it is available for all countries worldwide.*

Comment: Awesome! This was really helpful. Thanks for thr clarification, Janmenjaya!